# Website Broken in IE7

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

Site: http://bit.ly/nFJOWi

I have been debugging this site and have gotten it workin in IE8, IE9, FireFox, Chrome an Safari but the Homepage Featured box + Main NAV menu is appearing broken/out-of-place in IE7. Any thoughts or ideas what could be causing the problem?

Comment: The div positions inside 'featured' are missing and 'cause of that it's messing in IE. IE is hungry for CSS 'position's. Cause otherwise he thinks that he is smarter than you! ;)

Comment: Added some positions but I'm not sure what the best CSS is to fix this for IE7

Comment: Don't make us travel to another site in order to even get an Idea about what this question pertains to. Post code and ask or state a specific question please.

Comment: Don't post criticising peoples questions, either answer it or move along. This site is in Drupal 7 with multipel stylesheets and I have yet to pinpoint the problem hence the question. Use firebug to see the code.

Answer (score 2):

IE7 is probably the problem, the best thing I could think of is to add something like this to your page:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then overwrite the CSS rules you have created that work for the other browsers in your IE7.css stylesheet until you get it working in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I like to go about solving IE issues is by using conditional stylesheets
http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

put this code in the head of your document

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

then target ie7 by writing specific rules in your general stylesheet (saves http requests)
.ie7 div {zoom: 1;} (example)